# Postgres ON CONFLICT set column reference is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I have a table:

```
create table c (
    e text not null,
    m text not null,
    p numeric not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (e, m)
);
```

and I want to do insert or update that adds `p` to existing value:

```
insert into c values (...) on conflict (e, m) do update set
            p = p + excluded.p
```

and i get an error:

> ERROR: column reference "p" is ambiguous

how it's ambiguous? how should i write my insert to add `excluded.p` to the already existing value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you probably want:

```
        p = c.p + excluded.p
```

It is possible that you want:

```
        p = excluded.p + excluded.p
```

You need to specify.