# How do I insert multiple records with an ON CONFLICT UPDATE clause in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Given this table, which is just an example.

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
     order_id text primary key,
     payment_status text not null
)
```

I need to do an **upsert** on multiple records.

```
INSERT INTO orders(
        order_id, 
        payment_status
)
VALUES ('101','Paid'), ('102', 'Unpaid')
ON CONFLICT (order_id) DO UPDATE SET
        payment_status = payment_status;
```

`payment_status` returns as **ambiguous**.

The problem I'm trying to solve here is that I have a process that imports data but if it encounters a conflict, it needs to update the current data with the new data. (it's a historical table that sometimes gets new data for its history) I could break it up into single inserts, but that would have a dramatic performance cost.

I will need to update more than one column with this, as well, not just `payment_status` if that matters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On Insert: column reference "score" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378646/on-insert-column-reference-score-is-ambiguous), also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343169/postgres-on-conflict-set-column-reference-is-ambiguous https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161127/column-reference-is-ambiguous-when-upserting-element-into-table  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60324182/postgresql-sql-throws-ambiguous-column-error

Comment: While they all technically do, this was in the context of multiple inserts in one statement, which is where the answered solution is most useful. That's what I was googling (and stack overflowing) for and didn't find anything; though I'll admit in one related search, I did see `EXCLUDED` and mistook it as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`excluded`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.6.3.3) record:

```
INSERT INTO orders(
        order_id, 
        payment_status
)
VALUES ('101','Paid'), ('102', 'Unpaid')
ON CONFLICT (order_id) DO UPDATE 
   SET  payment_status = EXCLUDED.payment_status;
```

Comment: So simple! Thank you!